# TraceError: Proxy object cannot be iterated

Tags: python, object-detection, feature-extraction, torchvision, pre-trained-model

the most appropriate soln I found was this one
https://pytorch.org/vision/stable/feature_extraction.html but i end up w/ this error

`TraceError: Proxy object cannot be iterated. This can be attempted when the Proxy is used in a loop or as a *args or **kwargs function argument. See the torch.fx docs on pytorch.org for a more detailed explanation of what types of control flow can be traced, and check out the Proxy docstring for help troubleshooting Proxy iteration errors`

**My Code**

```
from torchvision.models.feature_extraction import create_feature_extractor
from torchvision.models.detection import fasterrcnn_mobilenet_v3_large_320_fpn

m = fasterrcnn_mobilenet_v3_large_320_fpn()

return_nodes = {
    'layer1': 'layer1'
}

create_feature_extractor(m, return_nodes=return_nodes)
return_nodes
```